# SQL pivot - trying to convert first row to columns

Tags: sql-server

I have data imported from a csv file that looks like this:

```
Name     Field     Year01     Year02 ... Year10
-----------------------------------------------
name     fieldname 2006       2007   ... 2015
xyz      field_a   123        999        222
xyz      field_b   111.1      123.4      456.7
abc      field_a   444        555        890
abc      field_b   999.9      888.8      789.0
```

which I need to look like this:

```
name  year   field_a   field_b
-----------------------------------------------
xyz   2006   123       111.1
xyz   2007   999       123.4
xyz   2015   222       456.7
...
abc   2006   444       999.9
abc   2007   555       888.8
abc   2015   890       789.0
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this using the Pivot instruction but can't seem to make it work.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` a `UNPIVOT` table. Steps:

1. Rename table columns
2. `UNPIVOT` by year
3. `PIVOT` by field

Complete query:

```
    WITH T1 AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES 
            ('name', 'fieldname', 2006, 2007, 2015), 
            ('xyz', 'field_a', 123  ,999  ,222  ),
            ('xyz', 'field_b', 111.1,123.4,456.7),
            ('abc', 'field_a', 444  ,555  ,890  ),
            ('abc', 'field_b', 999.9,888.8,789.0)
        ) AS T(Name,     Field,     Year01,     Year02, Year10)
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT Name AS name, Field AS fieldname, Year01 AS [2006], Year02 AS [2007], Year10 AS [2015]
        FROM T1
        WHERE Name <> 'name'
    ) AS T2
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [year] in ([2006], [2007], [2015])
    ) AS UP
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(value) FOR fieldname in (field_a, field_b)
    ) AS P
    ORDER BY name desc, [year]
```